# "srflx" candidate port doesn't match "host " candidate port

Tags: webrtc

I'm testing ice servers [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) from two machines located in different countries. Why do ports match in one case and don't in another? (49824 === 49824, 53371 === 2765)?

**Here'a result from one machine:**

```
0.004   1   host    2795255774  udp 192.168.1.7 49824   126 | 32542 | 255
0.130   1   srflx   264484875   udp 89.105.158.245  49824   100 | 32542 | 255
0.104   1   host    3894397742  tcp 192.168.1.7 9   90 | 32542 | 255
```

**Here'a result from another machine:**

```
0.010   1   host    1019731727  udp 192.168.1.104   53371   126 | 32542 | 255
0.109   1   srflx   3180321211  udp 178.90.249.178  2765    100 | 32542 | 255
0.112   1   host    1917068287  tcp 192.168.1.104   9   90 | 32542 | 255
```

Could this be the reason why I can't establish a WebRtc connection between these machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some NATs translate the port as well. If you want to get around NAT, a STUN server is simply not sufficient, you need TURN.

Comment: Different ports = [symmetric NAT](https://webrtchacks.com/symmetric-nat/) = need TURN